# JavaScript variable not is undefined in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have next JS code (this code not my own)

```
 function somename(f) 
    var procName = "";
    var procParams = new Array();
    var parseEl = "";
    var parseEls = new Array();
    var parseInd = 0;
    var procParamsInd = 0;
    var IsValRead = false;
    for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        if (f[i] == "(")
            break;
        else
            procName = procName + f[i];
    }

}
```

I will redo it to much better way to find data before "(", but i wounder why   procName variable is always undefined in IE9 in all browsers all working well.

Comment: please show the _actual_ error.

Comment: Works for me in the IE9 developer console

Comment: procName is undefined in for loop. and result is like undefinedundefinedundefinedundefined

Comment: Is procName undefined or f[x]?

Comment: f[x] actually it is parameter to function

Comment: I have a vague recollection that at least some versions of IE do not support indexing to access string characters. Try using charAt instead; or a better algorithm. It is almost certainly the f[x] which is causing your undefined's.

Comment: HBP Post it like answer I will choose it and you het some more point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a vague recollection that at least some versions of IE do not support indexing to access string characters. Try using charAt instead; or a better algorithm. It is almost certainly the f[x] which is causing your undefined's.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to get the substring before `(` is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gbW83/):

```
var f = "name(2,4,5)",
    procName = f.slice(0, f.indexOf('(')); //slice from start until before "("

console.log(procName)​; //name
```

Comment: Thanks this is nice. but question was about why procName is undefined in for.